# How does one specify one variable per line as Additional Arguments for the SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0 task?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, dacpac

I have a release pipeline in Azure DevOps that is responsible for creating a new database. To achieve this, I am using a DACPAC that includes a post deployment script which is responsible for seeding some data. To this end there are several variables that need to be provided.

When testing the DACPAC locally I am using the sqlpackage command via PowerShell and specifying arguments like this:

```
& sqlpackage `
/Action:publish `
/sf:path-to-dacpac `
/tdn:database-name `
/v:var_1="fizz" `
/v:var_2="buzz"
```

In the release pipeline I am using a SQL Server database deploy task. I would prefer to add one argument per line as in the PowerShell script above however, doing this causes the task to fail.

Here is the yaml produced when adding 1 argument per line:

```
variables:
  var_1: 'fizz'
  var_2: 'buzz'
  database: 'database-name'

steps:
- task: SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'Deploy using : dacpac'
  inputs:
    DacpacFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MyDatabase.dacpac'
    ServerName: 'SomeServerName'
    DatabaseName: '$(database)'
    AuthScheme: sqlServerAuthentication
    SqlUsername: 'username'
    SqlPassword: 'password'
    AdditionalArguments: |
     /v:var_1="$(var_1)"
     /v:var_2="$(var_2)"
```

Placing all the arguments on one line solves the issue but is terrible for readability (the actual DACPAC expects many more arguments that the example above.

So, is there an escape character that like in PowerShell so that I can split the arguments across several lines?